# e2e tests with error exceptions

Tags: jasmine, protractor

I'm working on some end to end tests with protractor, and I want to make some tests that simulate different errors on the login, like passwords don't match, or username does not exist, which at the moment is being handled on the server (parse.com).

I configured a few tests to sort of test this functionality (the project is early on) when a successful login triggers a page change and an unsuccessful login doesn't (so far they have not added any notification on the html for this).

Is it possible to do a more sort of unit type approach with protractor?

This is the code where the `Parse.User.logIn` is called which returns an error:

```js
Parse.User.logIn(($scope.user.username) , $scope.user.password, {
            success: function(_user) {
                console.log('Login Success');
                console.log('user = ' + _user.attributes.username);
                console.log('email = ' + _user.attributes.email);
                $ionicLoading.hide();
                $rootScope.user = _user;
                $rootScope.isLoggedIn = true;
                $state.go('tab.home');
            },
            error: function(user, err) {
                $ionicLoading.hide();
                // The login failed. Check error to see why.
                if (err.code === 101) {
                    $scope.error.message = 'Invalid login credentials';
                } else {
                    $scope.error.message = 'An unexpected error has ' +
                        'occurred, please try again.';
                }
                console.log('error message on Parse.User.logIn: ' + $scope.error.message);
                $scope.$apply();
            }
        });
```

Is there a way to set a test condition on the return of that error, or is that exclusively a unit test kind of thing?